# GitHub OAuth using Devise + OmniAuth

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got an application at http://github.com/rails3book/ticketee that contains an OAuth portion provided by Devise. The configuration is at `config/initializers/devise.rb`. I have got this working with Twitter but always get this "invalid credentials" message back from GitHub.

I cannot see what I am doing differently between Twitter and GitHub. To my knowledge, this should Just Work(tm).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is actually because GitHub's OAuth2 support doesn't mesh with the current draft of the OAuth2 specification. Basically, they want a parameter called "access_token" but the oauth2 gem's latest version (0.3.0 as of this writing) passes this through as "oauth_token", as the latest version of the draft requires.

This basically works with every other provider except GitHub because they haven't yet updated their support for this alternatively named parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Did you register your application with Github? Do you provide the correct keys? I have a similar authentication here, without Devise, however, configuration (in development.rb) should be nearly the same: http://github.com/markusproske/omniauth_pure

Edit: you need different registrations for development and production due to the callback route.

Comment: Strange. I had this error once where I had two initializers in my app with different keys, one in the initializers, one in development.rb. However, I doubt that you made this mistake too.  
You could test if your keys work in my omniauth_pure to eliminate one source of error.